# Google-App Engine client Auto generated files

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, apk, auto-generate

Currently i am working on google app engine and when i create an apk file from the project. It auto generate 3 files in my apk

1. org.codehaus.jackson.impl.VERSION.txt
2. com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jsom.VERSION.txt
3. com.google.api.client.googleapis.google.jks
   I want to know about these file??

I think first two file are for json reader but why there is 2 json readers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jsom` and `org.codehaus.jackson.impl` are both part of the [Jackson JSON library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload).

`com.google.api.client.googleapis.google.jks` is the [Google API Java library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).

I also guess the `VERSION.txt` files, since automatically generated, are just part of the build process.

What was your problem?